# Programming Pseudocode Nested if into Control Structure

Tags: pseudocode

Can anyone help me change this nested if into a control case, or something more efficient (just not loops)?

Design a solution for the following problem, use modules where possible. Illustrate your solution with structured flowcharts and corresponding pseudocode.

A health clinic has a payment schedule for any services provided which is as follows:

a.  If a patient is a first time patient with no insurance coverage, charges are to be paid in full at the time of service .

b.  If a patient is a first time patient with insurance coverage then one half of the 
charges are to be paid at the time of service and the balance billed on the
monthly statement.

c.  If a patient is not a first time patient with no insurance coverage then one half
of the charges are to be paid at the time of service and the balance billed on
the monthly statement.

d.  If a patient is not a first time patient with insurance coverage then the all
charges will be billed on the monthly statement.

e.  If a patient is a “preferred” patient with no insurance, one half of the charges
are to be paid that the time of service and the balance billed on the monthly
statement.

f.  If a patient is a “preferred” patient with insurance all charges will be billed on the monthly statement.

---

```
    Start
    Declare variables
    Input(first,ins,pre)
    if(first = 'T') then
        if(ins = 'T') then
            if(pre = 'T') then
                Print('Monthly Statement')
            else
                Print('Pay one-half and Billed one-half')
            endif
        else
            if(pre = 'T') then
                Print('Pay one-half and Billed one-half')
            else
                Print('Pay full')
            endif
        endif
    else
        if(ins = 'T') then
            if(pre = 'T') then
                Print('Monthly Statement')
            else
                Print('Monthly Statement')
            endif
        else
            if(pre = 'T') then
                Print('Pay one-half and Billed one-half')
            else
                Print('Pay one-half and Billed one-half')
            endif
        endif
    endif
    Stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than 3 booleans as you show, there seem to actually be two variables: kind of patient (3 values) and insurance status (2 values).

If you were trying to lay this out for a person, you'd probably draw a 3 x 2 table.

And there are 3 possible outcomes represented as strings.

So in this case I'd do the same thing with a 2d array:

```
enum PatientType { FirstTime, Normal, Preferred };
enum InsuranceStatus {  NotInsured, Insured };
string HalfAndHalf = 'Pay one-half and Billed one-half';
string InFull = 'Pay in full';
string Payments = 'Monthly statement';

string Result[PatientType][InsuranceStatus] = {
                     /* NotInsured */  /* Insured */
  /* FirstTime */ {  InFull,           HalfAndHalf }, 
  /* Normal    */ {  HalfAndHalf,      Payments    },
  /* Preferred */ {  HalfAndHalf,      Payments    }};
```

Now you can just index into the array `Result[patientType][insuranceStatus]` and print this string. The moral is data tables are often powerful for reducing code complexity and making it easy to change logic in the future.

If I got the spec wrong and it's actually 3 boolean independent variables, you can still use a 2x2x2 array.

Answer (score 0):

*Here is the answer that I posted to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/31409/9357).  I'm using Python as executable pseudocode.*

---

You must be working for American health care.  The key insight about American healthcare is that the first question is always "Do you have insurance?"  Indeed, if you restructure your code to ask that first, you'll find that the pattern will be more obvious.

```
if insured:
    if first:
        if preferred:
            print('Monthly Statement')
        else:
            print('Pay one-half and Billed one-half')
    else:
        if preferred then:
            print('Monthly Statement')
        else:
            print('Monthly Statement')
else:
    if first:
        if preferred:
            print('Pay one-half and Billed one-half')
        else:
            print('Pay full')
    else:
        if preferred:
            print('Pay one-half and Billed one-half')
        else:
            print('Pay one-half and Billed one-half')
```

The next goal is to consolidate to avoid repetition.  You'll notice that the "preferred" status only matters for first-time customers, so `(first and not preferred)` is a useful common expression; I've parenthesized them as such for emphasis.

Answer:

```
if (not insured) and (first and not preferred):
    pay_in_full()
elif (not insured) or (first and not preferred):
    pay_half_bill_half()
else:
    monthly_statement()
```

From there, you gain the insight that in general, insured patients get monthly bills, and uninsured patients pay half up front.  However, being `(first and not preferred)` carries a penalty of one degree of trustworthiness.  The following code implements this intuitive classification process.

```
# Actions
def pay_in_full():
    ...

def pay_half_bill_half():
    ...

def monthly_statement():
    ...

# Determine trust level
trust_levels = [pay_in_full, pay_half_bill_half, monthly_statement]
trust = 2 if insured else 1            # insured -> monthly. uninsured -> pay half
trust -= 1 if first and not preferred  # penalty for first-time unpreferred customers

# Call the code corresponding to the trust level
trust_levels[trust]()
```

It's up to you to decide whether you think the code based on truth-table minimization or on the intuitive classification is better.